# SQL Server management studio 2012 still using server 2005 instance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2012, ssms

I had previously installed SQL Server 2005 and its management tools. Now I have installed SQL Server 2012 and Management studio 2012 along with it. I did not uninstall the previous SQL Server 2005 before installing the server 2012.

Now the problem is that the management studio 2012 is still using the old instance of server 2005, which is creating troubles while restoring database, whose backup was taken with Server 2012.
[image: Here is a snapshot from management studio 2012]

How do I change the instance version to use SQL Server 2012 in Management studio.
If there is something I am doing wrong, or if there is any alternative, please tell.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.
Used `(LocalDb)\v11.0` as server name and it worked.

Comment: Accept your own answer so the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have both versions installed at once they must be using different instance names.

PC\SQLEXPRESS is 2005 instance, there must be another instance name for 2012 e.g. PC\SQL2012

You can find the instance name out in the SQL configuration manager.

Comment: Sorry, there is no other instance listed.